# How I can make kernel matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, kernel

I want to  make kernel matrix in R. On a data set X with n row and m columns it is defined:

```
     K(xi,xj)=-0.5*exp(sum{f=1 to m}(xif-xjf)^2).   i,j= 1,...,n
```

So it is a n * n matrix, any idea?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kernlab/versions/0.9-27/topics/kernelMatrix?